# redis invalid username-password pair witch dajngo channels but ok with CACHE and CACHEOPS

Tags: django-rest-framework, redis, django-channels

i have bellow error in my django app:

```
redis.exceptions.AuthenticationError: invalid username-password pair
```

my configuration in settings.py are :

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            #"hosts": [(config('REDIS_HOST'), config('REDIS_PORT', cast=int))],
            "hosts": ["redis://:password@localhost:6379/1"],
        },
    },
}


CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://:password@localhost:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            'MAX_ENTRIES' : 15000,
        },
        "KEY_PREFIX": "example"
    }
}
```

i have not any problem with cache conf but have invalid pass/user for channels!?
both using same redis.

Answer (score 0):

try this for **CHANNEL_LAYERS->default->CONFIG**

```
"hosts": [("<host:str>", <port:int>)],
```

or this

```
"hosts": ["redis://:password@127.0.0.1:6379/0"],
"symmetric_encryption_keys": [SECRET_KEY],
```

[channels_redis repo](https://github.com/django/channels_redis)

Comment: first config need pass, so i have added ''password" before config and i have this error : redis.exceptions.AuthenticationError: Authentication required.

second config : i have this error : redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error connecting to localhost:6379. SSL handshake is taking longer than 60.0 seconds: aborting the connection

Comment: may be something like this

`"hosts": ["redis://:password@127.0.0.1:6379/0"],
"symmetric_encryption_keys": [SECRET_KEY],`

Comment: read [symmetric_encryption_keys doc](https://github.com/django/channels_redis?tab=readme-ov-file#symmetric_encryption_keys)